# Merge data together based on an ID Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I currently have a set of data I pull back from an API in my java app. The data returned is along the lines of the following:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "receiptId": "123456",
  "selections": [
    {
      "name": "Apple",
      "price": "£1"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "receiptId": "678910",
  "selections": [
    {
      "name": "Pear",
      "price": "£0.5"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "receiptId": "123456",
  "selections": [
    {
      "name": "Banana",
      "price:": "£2.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, two of the `receiptId`'s are the same, I would like to merge any duplicate `receiptId's` data together to become one block. I.e:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "receiptId": "123456",
  "selections": [
    {
      "name": "Apple",
      "price": "£1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Banana",
      "price": "£2.00"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "receiptId": "678910",
  "selections": [
    {
      "name": "Pear",
      "price": "£0.5"
    }
  ]
},
```

Currently I am just streaming the data into a map by doing the following:

```
List<String> data = data.getData()
                         .stream()
                         .map(this::dataToReadable)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`dataToReadable` does the following:

```
  private String dataToReadable(List data) {
    return new DataBuilder().fromData(data)
                           .buildData();
  }
```

`fromData` does the following:

```
public DataBuilder fromData(List data) {
    this.withId(data.getId())
    this.withSelections(data.getSelections())
    this.withReceiptId(data.getReceiptId())
    return this;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works.

```
 data.getData()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getRecieptId))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(item -> dataToReadable(item.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this, I will need to re-stream out data in order to `collect` like this. And even then in the `Collector` I dont have access to any of `item`'s functions.

Comment: what does dataToReadable function do? what does it return

Comment: I've added a little more detail to the above.

Comment: I am already doing `dataToReadable` if possible I would like to re-stream the `data` list.

Comment: sorry didnt understood your question

Comment: do you understand now?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understood your comment. "I am already doing dataToReadable if possible I would like to re-stream the data list."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165051/discussion-between-davedavidson-and-pvpkiran).